# Make long path codes shorter in java

Tags: javascript, java

I am pretty new to programming so I am not sure what this is called but in Javascript, for example

```
arr[0].obj[0].getSomething();
```

can be shorten to

```
var o = arr[0].obj[0];
o.getSomething();
```

so that we do not have to repeat

```
arr[0].obj[0]
```

what is the equivalent of this in Java? I can't seem to find it.
Also tell me what should the title be, I am not sure whether my title is appropriate.

Comment: what is the class type for obj[0]? you had to write complete class name, afaik java is a strongly typed language unlike javascript you have pointed.

Comment: I suggest you read about variables, this is as basic as it gets.

Comment: the same thing in your case, if you are using Java-10+

Comment: It's basically the same

Comment: res = a + b + c can be also written as d = a + b, res = d + c. and its same everywhere, just making use of variables.

Comment: the syntax would also work in java! (only add the type of `var`, since java 10 `var` is also valid syntax), so: `Object o = arr[0].obj[0]; o.getSomething();` would work.

Comment: The thing you're describing is called a "variable".

Comment: @YCF_L and in versions before that, you just need the actual type, rather than `var`.

Comment: This pattern is also known as [extract variable](https://refactoring.guru/extract-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it just the same way:
If you have

```
House[] houses; // An array of houses

// initialize and fill the array
```

... and inside the `House` class you have a field `doors`:

```
public class House {

    Door[] doors;

    // Initialize the array in a constructor, add getter and setter methods
}
```

Then you can do either

```
Color doorColor = houses[0].doors[0].getColor();
```

or you store the door you want in a variable and then ask for its color:

```
Door door = houses[0].doors[0];
Color doorColor = door.getColor();
```

Comment: Nitpick: `doors` would have to exist inside each `House` object. Showing the arrays side by side like this might mislead beginners.

Answer (score 1):

With the given snipped I can understand your java code would look like as below.

```
class A{
    B obj[];
}

class B {
    public void doSomething(){}
}
```

lets say you have array of A class  object as as your code snippet says

```
arr[0].obj[0].getSomething();
```

in java it would be of class A like below

```
A arr[]
```

so the code would be

```
 arr[0].obj[0].doSomething();
```

we can write it as

```
A firstA = arr[0];
B firstB = firstA.obj[0];
firstB.doSomething();
```

or

```
B firstB = arr[0].obj[0];
firstB.doSomething();
```